# Autowiring doubts in spring?

Tags: spring

After going thru [autowiring concept](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html) 
i have got some questions. These are:-

- If  i need to autowire below class  `byType` or `byName` , is it mandatory to have `setStudent()` method in class College?

---

```
public class College {

  private Student student1;
  private String registration1;
}
```

---

- `<bean id="student1" class="Student"/>` - in case of `byname` it  will look into `id` attribute and in case of `bytype` it will look for `class` attribute in above
  Stetement. Right? If incase it finds two bean dean tags for the same type it will throw fatal error in case of `bytype`. Correct?
- autodetect Scenario chooses `constructor` or `byType` through introspection of the bean class. If a default constructor is found, the `byType` mode 
  will be applied.
  My question here  if default constructor is not found and constructor with argument is found then autowire by constructor
  will be applied. Correct?
- Do we need to specify  `@Autowired` somewhere in `College`  to apply the autowiring. As i can see this in [this example](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/spring/spring3/ioc/springautowiremodeno.html)
  but nothing is specified [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html)

Comment: Ignore anything on roseindia.net, it's generally badly written, misleading or just plain wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1), 4) There are two separate ways of autowiring in Spring: XML-based and annotaion-based.

XML-based autowiring is activated from XML config, as described [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-autowire). In the end, it will call setter method, so `setStudent()` method is required here.

Annonation-based autowiring, on the other hand, is performed via reflection magic. It attempts to fill everything you mark with `@Autowired` annotation. In fact, it can set private field with no accessors, as in

```
public class Foo {
    @Autowired private Thingy thing; // No getThing or setThing methods

    private void doStuff() {
       // thing is usable here
    }
}
```

For `@Autowired` annotaion to work, you will need to define corresponding bean post-processor; it is done by adding the following line to xml config:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

Note, that these two autowiring methods are independant, and it is possible(but not recommended) to use them simultaneously. In that case, xml autowiring will override annotations.

2) In general, autowiring will fail, if it cannot find one and only one candidate for injection. So, in your case, it will fail with exception upon container creation. There are some fallback quirks, but in general it works reliably.

3) Yes, documentaion says so.

About `byName` and `byType` autowiring. While `byName` autowiring simply tries to match bean name (can be specified with `id` attribute), `byType` is a bit more complex than `class` attribute lookup. It searches beans by *type*, and it will match interfaces. Example:

```
public interface SomeService {
    void doStuff();
}

public class SomeServiceImpl implements SomeService {
    @Override public void doStuff() {
        // Implementation
    };
}

public class ServiceUser {
    @Autowired
    private SomeService someService; // SomeServiceImpl instance goes here
}
```

P.S. You are referencing two different versions of Spring in your question, 2.5 and 3.0. Autowiring behavior is same in both.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Wanted to confirm the point2 with below example <bean id="student1" class="Student" autowire="byType"/> <bean id="address1" class="Address" /> <bean id="address2" class="Address"/> public class Student{ private Address someAddress; } do you mean to say that this will fail while BeanFactory factor1= new XmlBeanFactory(SomeXml); Right? Another point is- Autowire byname  will look into id attribute and  bytype  will look for class attribute in XML correct?

Comment: 2) Yes, it should work that way. Try to complie/run and read the exception message, it should clear things up.

Comment: @Mohit I've padded answer with byName/byType info.

Answer (score 1):

In Addition if you are using @Autwired annotation you need to mark the classes as candidates for autowiring. It should be done by using one of these annotations:

```
@Repository
@Service
@Component
@Controller
```

and of cause you can configure it in different scopes:

```
@Scope("prototype")
@Repository
public class MovieFinderImpl implements MovieFinder {
    // ...
}
```

Hope it makes it more clear.

Comment: That's only true for auto-detected components. It's not relevant to XML bean definitions.